# Assign text list to variable python

Tags: python, telethon

I have a python script which allows me to check if a number is used on telegram or not.

I try to change the variable "phone_number" to a .txt list which basically contain phone number (There is one phone number per line)
I want the script to take a phone number from the file.txt check if it exists or not then move on to the next one and so on until all the numbers are checked.

This is what i try so far...

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
import ast


api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    phone_in = []
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        phone_str = f.readline()
        phone_in.append(ast.literal_eval(phone_str))

    result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
        contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
            client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
            phone=phone_in,
            first_name='Some Name',
            last_name=''
        )]
    ))

    if len(result.users):
        print(f"{phone_in} has a telegram account")
        await client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(result.users))
    else:
        print(f"couldn't find an account for {phone_in}")

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I tried this but I had an error which is the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/phone.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/me/phone.py", line 17, in main
    result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 58, in _call
    future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/mtprotosender.py", line 174, in send
    state = RequestState(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/network/requeststate.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.data = bytes(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/tl/tlobject.py", line 194, in __bytes__
    return self._bytes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/tl/functions/contacts.py", line 498, in _bytes
    b'\x15\xc4\xb5\x1c',struct.pack('<i', len(self.contacts)),b''.join(x._bytes() for x in self.contacts),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/tl/functions/contacts.py", line 498, in <genexpr>
    b'\x15\xc4\xb5\x1c',struct.pack('<i', len(self.contacts)),b''.join(x._bytes() for x in self.contacts),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/tl/types/__init__.py", line 9789, in _bytes
    self.serialize_bytes(self.phone),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/tl/tlobject.py", line 112, in serialize_bytes
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: bytes or str expected, not <class 'list'>
```

Here is the same code but the phone number to check is "hardcoded"

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = XXXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    phone_number = '+XXXXXXXXX'
    result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
        contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
            client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
            phone=phone_number,
            first_name='Some Name',
            last_name=''
        )]
    ))

    if len(result.users):
        print(f"{phone_number} has a telegram account")
        await client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(result.users))
    else:
        print(f"couldn't find an account for {phone_number}")

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Does anyone know how I can assign the file.txt to the phone_in variable?

Comment: Well, what does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1):

If ImportContactsRequests expects one phone number at a time, then you have to call it for each phone number.  That will create multiple records for a single name, but if the API doesn't allow multiple phone numbers per person, you'll have to decide how to handle it.

```
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        phone_str = f.readline()

        result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
            contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
                client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
                phone=phone_str,
                first_name='Some Name',
                last_name=''
            )]
        ))

        if len(result.users):
            print(f"{phone_number} has a telegram account")
            await client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(result.users))
        else:
            print(f"couldn't find an account for {phone_number}")
```

Comment: Okay i just tried your code it works but it take only one number from the list then stop the process.
Telegram only allow one number per person if it's your question (i guess?)

Comment: So, if there are 3 numbers, what do you want to do?  Take the first?  Take the last?

Comment: take them one by one, in my list there is 10 phone numbers. i want to take the first row try if the phone numbers has a telegram account print if yes or no then go to the next one (row 2) and do a loop like this until there's no more phone number in the file.txt

Comment: You should have been able to figure this out.  I just didn't include the code to check result.users and delete the contact.  I can edit my answer, but it seems obvious.

Comment: maybe i'm dumb lol, can you edit it please ?

Comment: I don't mean to be insulting, but did you really not notice that I edited the answer 13 hours before you commented?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc of [InputPhoneContact](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/input_phone_contact.html), the `phone` argument takes `string` type not `list`. So you could read all phones in the `file.txt` first, then loop through the list.

```py
async def main():
    phone_in = []
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        phone_str = f.readline()
        phone_in.append(ast.literal_eval(phone_str))

    for phone in phone_in:
        result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
            contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
                client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
                phone=phone,
                first_name='Some Name',
                last_name=''
            )]
        ))
    
        if len(result.users):
            print(f"{phone} has a telegram account")
            await client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(result.users))
        else:
            print(f"couldn't find an account for {phone}")
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser, i just tried what you said but it didn't work... Maybe the problem is my list ?

Comment: @volvorod If it didn't work, what's the problem? Could you describe it?